# How to start tide server in Emacs For Mac OS X?

Tags: osx, server, gui-emacs

In the .spacemacs file, typescript configuration layer is

```
dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
'(
 ┆(typescript :variables
 ┆   ┆   ┆   ┆javascript-backend 'tide
 ┆   ┆   ┆   ┆typescript-fmt-tool 'prettier
 ┆   ┆   ┆   ┆typescript-linter 'eslint
 ┆   ┆   ┆   ┆typescript-fmt-on-save t)
```

When use [Emacs For Mac OS X](https://emacsformacosx.com/) open a nodejs project, this error happened on the status bar:

> eldoc error: (error Server does not exist. Run M-x tide-restart-server to start it again)

But even I run `tide-restart-server` via M-x, it still doesn't work.

If I open the project in terminal under the project folder, it can work perfectly.

What wrong in the GUI tool?